# INSERT QUERY multiple_query to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with my code wherein the images that has been uploaded is only one in the table wherein I've selected 5 images.

Here is my file-upload-employer.php

```
<?php 
    include('admin/db/database_configuration.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblalbums ORDER BY album_id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $wow = $row['album_id'];
       echo ($row['album_id']);
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
<?php
include('admin/db/database_configuration.php');
if (isset($_FILES["userfile"]) && !empty($_FILES["userfile"])) {
    $image = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

    $imageSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $imageType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $imageName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    if (empty($_POST['aname'])){$albumname = 'NULL'; } else{ $albumname ="'". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['aname']) . "'";}

    $len = count($image);
    $path = "admin/images/";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
         if (isset($imageName[$i]) && $imageName[$i] !== NULL) {
             if(move_uploaded_file($image[$i], $path.$imageName[$i])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblalum_photos` (imageName, imageSize, imageType, album_id) VALUES ('$imageName[$i]','$imageSize[$i]', '$imageType[$i]',$wow+1);";
                $sql .= "INSERT INTO `tblalbums` (albumName) VALUES ($albumname)";


                 if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    echo '<script>alert("Images Sent")</script>';
                    echo '<script>window.location = "contact_us.php"</script>';
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

here is the form wherein I put the Album name and select images.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="text" class="desc" name="aname" placeholder="Album Name" style="width: 250px;" />

    <?php include'admin/upload-preview.php' ?>
    <br><br>
    Select photo to send
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="result"> </div>
    <input id="files" type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple/><br>

    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="clear">CLEAR</button>

    <button id="yes" type="submit" name="save" formaction="file-upload-employer.php" class="btn btn-success">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

If I don't include the other sql `$sql .= "INSERT INTO tblalbums (albumName) VALUES ($albumname)";` it uploads correctly but I must have the album name together with the photos.

Thank you for future answers.

Comment: @SQLDBA as you can see in the insert statement the $wow variable is to be the value of the album_id for the table tblalbum_photos

Comment: It's likely due to trying to execute multiple statements at once.  If you separate them you'll probably have better luck.  On the off chance that that's not it, you may want to post any actual error messages that you're getting...

Comment: @AC got no errors but just wrong data that goes to my database.

Comment: @AC maybe lack of data goes to my database

Comment: You say the wrong data goes into the database. What's the data that goes in.

Comment: @Augwa it is suppose to be 5 images , but it only inserts 1

Comment: Well ... you're outputting some javascript right after the first query which redirects the browser, and cancels the rest of the script.